# Beginner: Using "With" outside a while-loop?

Tags: t-sql, while-loop

I've a beginner question.

This is a piece of code that works:

```
declare @RowNr int = 1
declare @CA int = 0

While @RowNr <= 1000
BEGIN
    With CCWithRow AS
    (
        SELECT CA ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by CA) as RowNr
        FROM myCATable
    )

    SELECT @CA = CA, @RowNr = RowNr
    FROM CCWithRow
    WHERE RowNr = @RowNr
    Set @RowNr +=  1

--Doing something with @CA here
END
```

This code doesn't:

```
    declare @RowNr int = 1
    declare @CA int = 0

    With CCWithRow AS
    (
            SELECT CA ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by CA) as RowNr
        FROM myCATable
    )

    While @RowNr <= 1000
    BEGIN
        SELECT @CA = CA, @RowNr = RowNr
        FROM CCWithRow
        WHERE RowNr = @RowNr
        Set @RowNr +=  1    
--Doing something with @CA here
    END
```

Question: Why do I have to "define" the WITH inside the loop?

I know that there are better ways to solve the original problem, so that shouldn't be the subject. Just want to know, why I can't define WITH outside of the loop and use it inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx)

> A common table expression (CTE) can be thought of as a temporary
>   result set that is defined within the execution scope of **a single**
>   SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or CREATE VIEW statement.

So the common table expression usage must **always** occur immediately after the end of the CTE definition as it is not in scope to reference anywhere else. This case is no exception.

Answer (score 1):

Thats the implementation of a CTE:

> A CTE can only be referenced by the statement that *immediately
>   follows the CTE*. This means that if you want to use a CTE, you must
>   write the query that refers to the CTE immediately after the CTE in
>   the T-SQL batch. ([ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163346.aspx#S2))

The result of a CTE is not a created object, its just a set of results based on the parsing of the CTE expression, much like a `(select ..)` subquery which similarly you cannot access elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, "not an object" is something I understand. Still choosing Martin for being faster. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Check the following statement on MSDN [Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx)

A common table expression (CTE) can be thought of as a temporary result set that is defined `within the execution scope of a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or CREATE VIEW statement.`

> It is not stored as an object and lasts only for the duration of the
>   query. It is immediately freed up after the preceded select statement
>   to CTE expression.

Check Microsoft Magazine article's section - [Structure of a CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163346.aspx#S2) for more information on CTE.

> The CTE is a language-level construct—meaning that SQL Server does not
>   internally create temp or virtual tables. The CTE's underlying query
>   will be called each time it is referenced in the immediately following
>   query.